# Android Java Return Result from Async Task in Background Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, design-patterns, delegates

**How return a result from AsyncTask void onPostExecute() method in Java Android in Background Task?
I had lost a lot days searching about it when Delegate Pattern Save My Life save my life. When had found here from StackOverFlow.**

My Main Thread has a CsvUtil.getCompanies() method who need to return a List, and getCompanies() call a ReadLine class who consume a Google Sheet from Cloud.

```
public static final class ParseLine extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {
        private TaskDelegate delegate;

        public ParseLine(TaskDelegate delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        public interface TaskDelegate {
            public void onTaskEndWithResult(String[] parseLine);
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... nextLine) {
            try {
                return parseLine(nextLine[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("CsvReader", ex.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] parseLine) {
            if (parseLine != null && delegate != null)
                delegate.onTaskEndWithResult(parseLine);
        }
    }

private static final class GetNextLine extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
        implements ParseLine.TaskDelegate {

        private List<String[]> list;

        public GetNextLine(List<String[]> l) {
            list = l;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... companies) {
            try {
                return getNextLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("CsvReader", ex.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String nextLine) {
            if (nextLine != null) {
                ParseLine parseLine = new ParseLine(this);
                parseLine.execute(nextLine);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskEndWithResult(String[] parseLine) {
            list.add(parseLine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I need use Background Task and Delegate Pattern?

Comment: `onPostExecute` is called on UI Thread, it is basically a callback which is called when `doInBackground` finishes, either having result or not. It is not clear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: So, I need return the result from void onPostExecute to my Main Thread, passing from two Background Threads.

Comment: If you launch 2 `AsyncTasks` then both will give you result in their `onPostExecute` methods. There you can get your result and update UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private static WeakReference<MainActivity> activityRef ;

        public BackgroundTask(MainActivity activity){
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            MainActivity activity = activityRef.get();

            if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()){
                //Talk to activity
            }
        }
    }
```

You can do it this:

(I didn't understand your question complety but where did i found you wish to talk to underline activity from asyncTask if you wish to do opposite activity to asyncTask you can use interface approach or model view model approach)

Comment: I have 2 Background Threads Passing Result Each Other, so my doubt is when use Delegate Pattern and if is recommended using 2 Background Threads.